# No data is fetched using MVVM and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2

I am trying to use `MVVM` on my app to fetch some data using `Retrofit`, and display it on a `RecyclerView`, however nothing is being displayed, the data is being logged and when I call the retrofit instance directly from my activity, data is being displayed on my `RecyclerView`, not sure what am doing wrong.

Here is how my adapter looks like

```
    class CategoryAdapter (val context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryView>(){

    var category : List<Category> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryAdapter.CategoryView {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false)
        return CategoryView(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return category.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:CategoryView, position: Int) {
        val category = category[position]

        holder.categoryName.text = category.name

    }


    class CategoryView(itemView: View, var category: Category? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val categoryName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title)

    }

}
```

My `ViewModel`

```
fun loadCategories(id:Int): MutableLiveData<List<Category>>? {
    var categoryList: MutableLiveData<List<Category>>? = null

    RetrofitClient.makeRetrofitApi2().getCategoryProducts(id)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<List<Category>> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Category>>, response: Response<List<Category>>) {
                    categoryList?.value = response.body()
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Category>>, t: Throwable) {

                }
            })

    return categoryList
    }
```

How I call it in my activity

```
private fun productRecyclerView(){

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.foodRv)
    categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = categoryAdapter


    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
    userViewModel!!.loadCategories(intent.getIntExtra("VENDOR_ID", 0))?.observe(this, Observer { categories ->

        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(this)
        categoryAdapter!!.setCategories(categories)
        foodRv!!.adapter = categoryAdapter

    })
}
```

Everything is initialised.

Comment: You didn't initialize `categoryList` in `loadCategories()` function, you set it to null but never assigned it

Comment: is the API call successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized the `Adapter` again inside the `Observer` and set it to `foodRv`. Was that on purpose?

If you need the `recyclerView` to display your categories, you can just do this:

```
categoryAdapter!!.setCategories(categories)
categoryAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize categoryList in viewModel as it's value is null like this :

```
 var categoryList: MutableLiveData<List<Category>>? = MutableLiveData<>()
```

on the first time the adapter works with 0 items so nothing appears, after setting the newly fetched categories to the adapter you need to inform it to re-inflate the items using DiffUtils or simply `notifyDataSetChanged()`